# How do I fix the crazy spacing in my javascript slider, which uses 100% widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a slider on my client's site that was working fine until I made it's containers use the calculate width webkit properties, and the 100% properties.

I finally managed to get all the containers and the images to resize together, but now the slider images have a huge amount of space between each one when you scroll through.

Here is a link to the page. (***you will need to resize your browser to be less than 1080 pixels wide in order to see the slider version I'm talking about***): http://agentboris.com/index2.php

```js
/*
TouchSlider 0.95
Licensed under the MIT license.
http://touchslider.com
*/
(function(a,b){window.touchSlider=function(c){function s(a){n.removeClass(c.currentClass).eq(a).addClass(c.currentClass)}function t(a,c){var d=f.current;d!==a&&(a=a!==b?a:d+1,q.to(a,{complete:c}))}function u(a){q.to(f.current+1,{dirX:1,complete:a})}function v(a){q.to(f.current-1,{dirX:-1,complete:a})}function z(){x&&A()}function A(){return x=!0,w||(clearTimeout(y),y=setTimeout(function(){!q.moving&&!w&&u()},c.delay)),c.container}function B(){return clearTimeout(y),x=!1,c.container}function C(){var b=a(document),c,e,f=!1,m,n,o,p,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z=function(a){if(a.which>1)return;f&&b.triggerHandler(j+"."+d),f=!0,e=!1,c=a.timeStamp,s=x=0,m=[0,0,0,c];if(a.originalEvent.touches){b.one(h,A);return}a.preventDefault(),o=p=a.pageX,v=w=a.pageY,u=l[0].offsetLeft,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j+"."+d,C),q.moveStart(a)},A=function(a){if(a.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;o=p=a.pageX=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,v=w=a.pageY=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t=y=0,u=(new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(l[0]).webkitTransform)).e,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j,C),q.moveStart(a)},B=function(b){var c,d;if(b.originalEvent.touches&&g){if(b.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;c=b.pageX=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,d=b.pageY=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t+=Math.abs(c-p),y+=Math.abs(d-w);if(Math.abs(t-y)>50){var f=t;t=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,t-y)),y=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,y-f))}if(c===p)return;e||(t>y?(b.preventDefault(),e=!0):C(b))}else{c=b.pageX,d=b.pageY;if(c===p)return;a.browser.msie&&b.preventDefault()}s+=Math.abs(c-p),x+=Math.abs(d-w),m.shift(),m.push(b.timeStamp),n.shift(),n.push(c),q.move(b,p),p=c,w=d},C=function(a){f=!1;if(!a.originalEvent||a.originalEvent.touches)a.pageX=p,a.pageY=w;b.unbind(i,B);var d=m.length,e=0,g=0;while(--d>0)if(m[d-1]){var h=n[d]-n[d-1];e+=Math.abs(h)/(m[d]-m[d-1]),h!==0&&(g=h>0?-1:1)}e/=m.length,q.moveEnd(a,e,g,c,s,x),r=!1,s+x>4&&k.one("click",function(a){a.preventDefault()})};k.bind(h,z)}c=c||{};var d=c.namespace||"touchslider",e=a(c.container);if(e.length!==1){e.each(function(){touchSlider({container:this})});return}c=a.extend({autoplay:!1,delay:3e3,margin:5,viewport:"."+d+"-viewport",prev:"."+d+"-prev",next:"."+d+"-next",pagination:"."+d+"-nav-item",currentClass:d+"-nav-item-current",duration:350,mouseTouch:!0},c);var f={current:0,step:t,next:u,prev:v,start:A,stop:B},g="ontouchstart"in window&&"WebKitCSSMatrix"in window,h="touchstart",i="touchmove",j="touchend",k=a(c.viewport,e),l=c.scroller?a(c.scroller,e):k.children(),m=l.children(),n=a(c.pagination,e);if(l.css("position")!=="absolute"){var o=k.height();k.css({height:o,position:"relative"}),l.css({position:"absolute",left:0,height:o,width:1e5})}g||(h="mousedown",i="mousemove",j="mouseup"),m.css("position","absolute");var p=g?function(a,c,d){if(c===b)return(new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle(a.jquery?a[0]:a).webkitTransform)).e;a.css({webkitTransitionDuration:d?d+"ms":"0",webkitTransform:function(a){return"translate3d("+(typeof c=="number"?c:c.call(this,a))+"px,0,0)"}})}:function(a,c){if(c===b)return parseInt((a.jquery?a[0]:a).style.left,10);a.css("left",c)};g&&m.css({webkitTransitionProperty:"-webkit-transform",webkitTransitionTimingFunction:"cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1)"}),p(m.not(m[0]),1e4),p(m.eq(0),0);var q=function(){var d=[0],e=[0],h=a.noop;return{moving:!1,init:function(){l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){h()})},to:function(i,j){j=j||{},i>=m.length?i=0:i<0&&(i=m.length-1);var k=c.duration,n=m.eq(i),o=a.inArray(i,d),r=0;l.stop(),q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y);if(o!==-1)r=e[o];else{var t,u=m.index(n);o=b;if(j.dirX===-1)e.unshift(0),d.unshift(u);else if(j.dirX===1)e.push(0),d.push(u);else{for(t=d.length-1;t>=0;t--)if(d[t]<u){e.splice(t+1,0,0),d.splice(t+1,0,u),o=0;break}o===b&&(e.unshift(e),d.unshift(u))}o=a.inArray(u,d);if(o===0)r=e[1]-(n.outerWidth()+c.margin),p(n,r),e[o]=r;else if(o===d.length-1)r=e[o-1]+m.eq(d[o-1]).outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,r),e[o]=r;else{var v=n.outerWidth();n.css("opacity",0),r=e[o+1]-Math.round((v+c.margin)/2),e[o]=r,p(n,r);var w=r,x=d.length;for(t=o-1;t>=0;t--)w-=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=w;var A=r;for(t=o+1;t<x;t++)A+=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=A;for(t=0;t<x;t++)m.eq(d[t]).animate({left:e[t]},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:function(){n.is(this)&&n.animate({opacity:1},k)}})}}j.pxInMs&&(k=Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(Math.abs(p(l))/j.pxInMs),100),k)),h=function(){p(m.not(n),-1e4),d=[m.index(n)],e=[r],j.complete&&j.complete(),q.moving=!1,z()},g?p(l,-r,k):l.animate({left:-r},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:h}),f.current=i,s(i)},stop:function(){g?p(l,p(l)):l.stop()},moveStart:function(a){q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y),l.stop(),q.startPageX=a.pageX;var b=p(l),c;q.leftCount=b,d[0]===0?e[0]+b>0&&(q.leftCount=b+(e[0]+b)*3):d[d.length-1]===m.length-1&&(c=e[d.length-1]+b,c<0&&(q.leftCount=b+c*3))},move:function(a,b){var f=a.pageX-b,g=p(l),h=m.eq(d[0]),i=d.length-1,j=m.eq(d[i]),n,o,r;q.leftCount+=f;if(f>0)while(d[0]!==0&&g+e[0]+f>c.margin)n=m.eq(d[0]-1),o=e[0]-n.outerWidth()-c.margin,p(n,o),e.unshift(o),d.unshift(d[0]-1),i++,h=n;(f>0&&g+e[0]+f>0||f<0&&g+e[0]>0)&&d[0]===0&&(r=Math.min(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[0])/4),k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[0]));if(f<0)while(!j.is(m.last())&&g+e[i]+f+j.outerWidth()+c.margin<k.innerWidth())n=m.eq(d[i]+1),o=e[i]+j.outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,o),e.push(o),d.push(d[i++]+1),j=n;(f>0&&g+e[i]<0||f<0&&g+e[i]+f<0)&&j.is(m.last())&&(r=Math.max(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[i])/4),-k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[i])),p(l,g+f)},moveEnd:function(a,b,c,f,g,h){var i=d.length,j=p(l),n=i-1,o;if(e[0]+j>0)n=0;else if(!(e[d.length-1]+j<0)){o={pxInMs:b};var s,t,u=i-1,v=k.innerWidth();for(s=0;s<i-1;s++){t=e[s]+m.eq(d[s]).outerWidth()+j;if(t>0&&t>v-(e[s+1]+j)){u=s;break}}if(r)n=u;else{var w=i-1,x=Math.round(l.offset().left);for(s=0;s<i;s++)if(e[s]+x>a.pageX){w=s-1;break}n=u,u===w&&a.timeStamp-f<1e3&&g+h>Math.sqrt(Math.pow(k.height(),2)+Math.pow(v,2))*.05&&(n=Math.max(0,Math.min(i-1,n+c)))}}n=d[n],q.to(n,o)}}}();q.init();if(g){var r=!1;l.bind("webkitTransitionStart",function(){r=!0}),l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){r=!1})}var w=!1,x=!1,y;k.hover(function(){clearTimeout(y),w=!0},function(){w=!1,z()}),n.click(function(){t(n.index(this))}),a(c.prev,e).click(function(){v()}),a(c.next,e).click(function(){u()}),c.mouseTouch&&C(),c.autoplay&&A(),e.data(d,f)},a.fn.touchSlider=function(a){return a=a||{},a.container=this,touchSlider(a),this}})(jQuery);
(function(a,b){window.touchSlider=function(c){function s(a){n.removeClass(c.currentClass).eq(a).addClass(c.currentClass)}function t(a,c){var d=f.current;d!==a&&(a=a!==b?a:d+1,q.to(a,{complete:c}))}function u(a){q.to(f.current+1,{dirX:1,complete:a})}function v(a){q.to(f.current-1,{dirX:-1,complete:a})}function z(){x&&A()}function A(){return x=!0,w||(clearTimeout(y),y=setTimeout(function(){!q.moving&&!w&&u()},c.delay)),c.container}function B(){return clearTimeout(y),x=!1,c.container}function C(){var b=a(document),c,e,f=!1,m,n,o,p,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z=function(a){if(a.which>1)return;f&&b.triggerHandler(j+"."+d),f=!0,e=!1,c=a.timeStamp,s=x=0,m=[0,0,0,c];if(a.originalEvent.touches){b.one(h,A);return}a.preventDefault(),o=p=a.pageX,v=w=a.pageY,u=l[0].offsetLeft,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j+"."+d,C),q.moveStart(a)},A=function(a){if(a.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;o=p=a.pageX=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,v=w=a.pageY=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t=y=0,u=(new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(l[0]).webkitTransform)).e,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j,C),q.moveStart(a)},B=function(b){var c,d;if(b.originalEvent.touches&&g){if(b.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;c=b.pageX=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,d=b.pageY=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t+=Math.abs(c-p),y+=Math.abs(d-w);if(Math.abs(t-y)>50){var f=t;t=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,t-y)),y=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,y-f))}if(c===p)return;e||(t>y?(b.preventDefault(),e=!0):C(b))}else{c=b.pageX,d=b.pageY;if(c===p)return;a.browser.msie&&b.preventDefault()}s+=Math.abs(c-p),x+=Math.abs(d-w),m.shift(),m.push(b.timeStamp),n.shift(),n.push(c),q.move(b,p),p=c,w=d},C=function(a){f=!1;if(!a.originalEvent||a.originalEvent.touches)a.pageX=p,a.pageY=w;b.unbind(i,B);var d=m.length,e=0,g=0;while(--d>0)if(m[d-1]){var h=n[d]-n[d-1];e+=Math.abs(h)/(m[d]-m[d-1]),h!==0&&(g=h>0?-1:1)}e/=m.length,q.moveEnd(a,e,g,c,s,x),r=!1,s+x>4&&k.one("click",function(a){a.preventDefault()})};k.bind(h,z)}c=c||{};var d=c.namespace||"touchslider",e=a(c.container);if(e.length!==1){e.each(function(){touchSlider({container:this})});return}c=a.extend({autoplay:!1,delay:3e3,margin:5,viewport:"."+d+"-viewport",prev:"."+d+"-prev",next:"."+d+"-next",pagination:"."+d+"-nav-item",currentClass:d+"-nav-item-current",duration:350,mouseTouch:!0},c);var f={current:0,step:t,next:u,prev:v,start:A,stop:B},g="ontouchstart"in window&&"WebKitCSSMatrix"in window,h="touchstart",i="touchmove",j="touchend",k=a(c.viewport,e),l=c.scroller?a(c.scroller,e):k.children(),m=l.children(),n=a(c.pagination,e);if(l.css("position")!=="absolute"){var o=k.height();k.css({height:o,position:"relative"}),l.css({position:"absolute",left:0,height:o,width:1e5})}g||(h="mousedown",i="mousemove",j="mouseup"),m.css("position","absolute");var p=g?function(a,c,d){if(c===b)return(new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle(a.jquery?a[0]:a).webkitTransform)).e;a.css({webkitTransitionDuration:d?d+"ms":"0",webkitTransform:function(a){return"translate3d("+(typeof c=="number"?c:c.call(this,a))+"px,0,0)"}})}:function(a,c){if(c===b)return parseInt((a.jquery?a[0]:a).style.left,10);a.css("left",c)};g&&m.css({webkitTransitionProperty:"-webkit-transform",webkitTransitionTimingFunction:"cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1)"}),p(m.not(m[0]),1e4),p(m.eq(0),0);var q=function(){var d=[0],e=[0],h=a.noop;return{moving:!1,init:function(){l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){h()})},to:function(i,j){j=j||{},i>=m.length?i=0:i<0&&(i=m.length-1);var k=c.duration,n=m.eq(i),o=a.inArray(i,d),r=0;l.stop(),q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y);if(o!==-1)r=e[o];else{var t,u=m.index(n);o=b;if(j.dirX===-1)e.unshift(0),d.unshift(u);else if(j.dirX===1)e.push(0),d.push(u);else{for(t=d.length-1;t>=0;t--)if(d[t]<u){e.splice(t+1,0,0),d.splice(t+1,0,u),o=0;break}o===b&&(e.unshift(e),d.unshift(u))}o=a.inArray(u,d);if(o===0)r=e[1]-(n.outerWidth()+c.margin),p(n,r),e[o]=r;else if(o===d.length-1)r=e[o-1]+m.eq(d[o-1]).outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,r),e[o]=r;else{var v=n.outerWidth();n.css("opacity",0),r=e[o+1]-Math.round((v+c.margin)/2),e[o]=r,p(n,r);var w=r,x=d.length;for(t=o-1;t>=0;t--)w-=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=w;var A=r;for(t=o+1;t<x;t++)A+=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=A;for(t=0;t<x;t++)m.eq(d[t]).animate({left:e[t]},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:function(){n.is(this)&&n.animate({opacity:1},k)}})}}j.pxInMs&&(k=Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(Math.abs(p(l))/j.pxInMs),100),k)),h=function(){p(m.not(n),-1e4),d=[m.index(n)],e=[r],j.complete&&j.complete(),q.moving=!1,z()},g?p(l,-r,k):l.animate({left:-r},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:h}),f.current=i,s(i)},stop:function(){g?p(l,p(l)):l.stop()},moveStart:function(a){q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y),l.stop(),q.startPageX=a.pageX;var b=p(l),c;q.leftCount=b,d[0]===0?e[0]+b>0&&(q.leftCount=b+(e[0]+b)*3):d[d.length-1]===m.length-1&&(c=e[d.length-1]+b,c<0&&(q.leftCount=b+c*3))},move:function(a,b){var f=a.pageX-b,g=p(l),h=m.eq(d[0]),i=d.length-1,j=m.eq(d[i]),n,o,r;q.leftCount+=f;if(f>0)while(d[0]!==0&&g+e[0]+f>c.margin)n=m.eq(d[0]-1),o=e[0]-n.outerWidth()-c.margin,p(n,o),e.unshift(o),d.unshift(d[0]-1),i++,h=n;(f>0&&g+e[0]+f>0||f<0&&g+e[0]>0)&&d[0]===0&&(r=Math.min(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[0])/4),k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[0]));if(f<0)while(!j.is(m.last())&&g+e[i]+f+j.outerWidth()+c.margin<k.innerWidth())n=m.eq(d[i]+1),o=e[i]+j.outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,o),e.push(o),d.push(d[i++]+1),j=n;(f>0&&g+e[i]<0||f<0&&g+e[i]+f<0)&&j.is(m.last())&&(r=Math.max(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[i])/4),-k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[i])),p(l,g+f)},moveEnd:function(a,b,c,f,g,h){var i=d.length,j=p(l),n=i-1,o;if(e[0]+j>0)n=0;else if(!(e[d.length-1]+j<0)){o={pxInMs:b};var s,t,u=i-1,v=k.innerWidth();for(s=0;s<i-1;s++){t=e[s]+m.eq(d[s]).outerWidth()+j;if(t>0&&t>v-(e[s+1]+j)){u=s;break}}if(r)n=u;else{var w=i-1,x=Math.round(l.offset().left);for(s=0;s<i;s++)if(e[s]+x>a.pageX){w=s-1;break}n=u,u===w&&a.timeStamp-f<1e3&&g+h>Math.sqrt(Math.pow(k.height(),2)+Math.pow(v,2))*.05&&(n=Math.max(0,Math.min(i-1,n+c)))}}n=d[n],q.to(n,o)}}}();q.init();if(g){var r=!1;l.bind("webkitTransitionStart",function(){r=!0}),l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){r=!1})}var w=!1,x=!1,y;k.hover(function(){clearTimeout(y),w=!0},function(){w=!1,z()}),n.click(function(){t(n.index(this))}),a(c.prev,e).click(function(){v()}),a(c.next,e).click(function(){u()}),c.mouseTouch&&C(),c.autoplay&&A(),e.data(d,f)},a.fn.touchSlider=function(a){return a=a||{},a.container=this,touchSlider(a),this}})(jQuery);
```

```css
.touchslider{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);}


.touchslider-viewport{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}

.touchslider-viewport-div{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}

.touchslider-item{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}

.touchslider-viewport-div-image{
width: -webkit-calc(100vw - 25px);
width:    -moz-calc(100vw - 25px);
width:         calc(100vw - 25px);
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="touchslider hideslide">


<div class="touchslider-viewport">


<div class="touchslider-viewport-div">
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/20b-woodlawn.php"><img src="slider/20b-woodlawn.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image"  /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/73-macpherson.php"><img src="slider/73-macpherson.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/232-lonsmount.php"><img src="slider/232-lonsmount.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="slider/sign.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></div>



</div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(".touchslider").touchSlider({container: this,
duration: 800, // the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
delay: 5000, // initial auto-scrolling delay for each loop 
margin: 3, // borders size. The margin is set in pixels.
mouseTouch: true,
namespace: "touchslider",
next: ".touchslider-next", // jQuery object for the elements to which a "scroll forwards" action should be bound.
pagination: ".touchslider-nav-item",
currentClass: "touchslider-nav-item-current", // class name for current     pagination item.
prev: ".touchslider-prev", // jQuery object for the elements to which a     "scroll backwards" action should be bound.
autoplay: true, // Activate auto-scrolling, choose either "true" or "false"
viewport: ".touchslider-viewport"});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly adding `overflow: hidden` to `.touchslider-viewport` fixes your issue. Absurdly large width of container is now hidden, but sliding still works.

```js
/*
TouchSlider 0.95
Licensed under the MIT license.
http://touchslider.com
*/
(function(a,b){window.touchSlider=function(c){function s(a){n.removeClass(c.currentClass).eq(a).addClass(c.currentClass)}function t(a,c){var d=f.current;d!==a&&(a=a!==b?a:d+1,q.to(a,{complete:c}))}function u(a){q.to(f.current+1,{dirX:1,complete:a})}function v(a){q.to(f.current-1,{dirX:-1,complete:a})}function z(){x&&A()}function A(){return x=!0,w||(clearTimeout(y),y=setTimeout(function(){!q.moving&&!w&&u()},c.delay)),c.container}function B(){return clearTimeout(y),x=!1,c.container}function C(){var b=a(document),c,e,f=!1,m,n,o,p,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z=function(a){if(a.which>1)return;f&&b.triggerHandler(j+"."+d),f=!0,e=!1,c=a.timeStamp,s=x=0,m=[0,0,0,c];if(a.originalEvent.touches){b.one(h,A);return}a.preventDefault(),o=p=a.pageX,v=w=a.pageY,u=l[0].offsetLeft,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j+"."+d,C),q.moveStart(a)},A=function(a){if(a.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;o=p=a.pageX=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,v=w=a.pageY=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t=y=0,u=(new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(l[0]).webkitTransform)).e,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j,C),q.moveStart(a)},B=function(b){var c,d;if(b.originalEvent.touches&&g){if(b.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;c=b.pageX=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,d=b.pageY=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t+=Math.abs(c-p),y+=Math.abs(d-w);if(Math.abs(t-y)>50){var f=t;t=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,t-y)),y=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,y-f))}if(c===p)return;e||(t>y?(b.preventDefault(),e=!0):C(b))}else{c=b.pageX,d=b.pageY;if(c===p)return;a.browser.msie&&b.preventDefault()}s+=Math.abs(c-p),x+=Math.abs(d-w),m.shift(),m.push(b.timeStamp),n.shift(),n.push(c),q.move(b,p),p=c,w=d},C=function(a){f=!1;if(!a.originalEvent||a.originalEvent.touches)a.pageX=p,a.pageY=w;b.unbind(i,B);var d=m.length,e=0,g=0;while(--d>0)if(m[d-1]){var h=n[d]-n[d-1];e+=Math.abs(h)/(m[d]-m[d-1]),h!==0&&(g=h>0?-1:1)}e/=m.length,q.moveEnd(a,e,g,c,s,x),r=!1,s+x>4&&k.one("click",function(a){a.preventDefault()})};k.bind(h,z)}c=c||{};var d=c.namespace||"touchslider",e=a(c.container);if(e.length!==1){e.each(function(){touchSlider({container:this})});return}c=a.extend({autoplay:!1,delay:3e3,margin:5,viewport:"."+d+"-viewport",prev:"."+d+"-prev",next:"."+d+"-next",pagination:"."+d+"-nav-item",currentClass:d+"-nav-item-current",duration:350,mouseTouch:!0},c);var f={current:0,step:t,next:u,prev:v,start:A,stop:B},g="ontouchstart"in window&&"WebKitCSSMatrix"in window,h="touchstart",i="touchmove",j="touchend",k=a(c.viewport,e),l=c.scroller?a(c.scroller,e):k.children(),m=l.children(),n=a(c.pagination,e);if(l.css("position")!=="absolute"){var o=k.height();k.css({height:o,position:"relative"}),l.css({position:"absolute",left:0,height:o,width:1e5})}g||(h="mousedown",i="mousemove",j="mouseup"),m.css("position","absolute");var p=g?function(a,c,d){if(c===b)return(new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle(a.jquery?a[0]:a).webkitTransform)).e;a.css({webkitTransitionDuration:d?d+"ms":"0",webkitTransform:function(a){return"translate3d("+(typeof c=="number"?c:c.call(this,a))+"px,0,0)"}})}:function(a,c){if(c===b)return parseInt((a.jquery?a[0]:a).style.left,10);a.css("left",c)};g&&m.css({webkitTransitionProperty:"-webkit-transform",webkitTransitionTimingFunction:"cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1)"}),p(m.not(m[0]),1e4),p(m.eq(0),0);var q=function(){var d=[0],e=[0],h=a.noop;return{moving:!1,init:function(){l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){h()})},to:function(i,j){j=j||{},i>=m.length?i=0:i<0&&(i=m.length-1);var k=c.duration,n=m.eq(i),o=a.inArray(i,d),r=0;l.stop(),q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y);if(o!==-1)r=e[o];else{var t,u=m.index(n);o=b;if(j.dirX===-1)e.unshift(0),d.unshift(u);else if(j.dirX===1)e.push(0),d.push(u);else{for(t=d.length-1;t>=0;t--)if(d[t]<u){e.splice(t+1,0,0),d.splice(t+1,0,u),o=0;break}o===b&&(e.unshift(e),d.unshift(u))}o=a.inArray(u,d);if(o===0)r=e[1]-(n.outerWidth()+c.margin),p(n,r),e[o]=r;else if(o===d.length-1)r=e[o-1]+m.eq(d[o-1]).outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,r),e[o]=r;else{var v=n.outerWidth();n.css("opacity",0),r=e[o+1]-Math.round((v+c.margin)/2),e[o]=r,p(n,r);var w=r,x=d.length;for(t=o-1;t>=0;t--)w-=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=w;var A=r;for(t=o+1;t<x;t++)A+=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=A;for(t=0;t<x;t++)m.eq(d[t]).animate({left:e[t]},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:function(){n.is(this)&&n.animate({opacity:1},k)}})}}j.pxInMs&&(k=Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(Math.abs(p(l))/j.pxInMs),100),k)),h=function(){p(m.not(n),-1e4),d=[m.index(n)],e=[r],j.complete&&j.complete(),q.moving=!1,z()},g?p(l,-r,k):l.animate({left:-r},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:h}),f.current=i,s(i)},stop:function(){g?p(l,p(l)):l.stop()},moveStart:function(a){q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y),l.stop(),q.startPageX=a.pageX;var b=p(l),c;q.leftCount=b,d[0]===0?e[0]+b>0&&(q.leftCount=b+(e[0]+b)*3):d[d.length-1]===m.length-1&&(c=e[d.length-1]+b,c<0&&(q.leftCount=b+c*3))},move:function(a,b){var f=a.pageX-b,g=p(l),h=m.eq(d[0]),i=d.length-1,j=m.eq(d[i]),n,o,r;q.leftCount+=f;if(f>0)while(d[0]!==0&&g+e[0]+f>c.margin)n=m.eq(d[0]-1),o=e[0]-n.outerWidth()-c.margin,p(n,o),e.unshift(o),d.unshift(d[0]-1),i++,h=n;(f>0&&g+e[0]+f>0||f<0&&g+e[0]>0)&&d[0]===0&&(r=Math.min(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[0])/4),k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[0]));if(f<0)while(!j.is(m.last())&&g+e[i]+f+j.outerWidth()+c.margin<k.innerWidth())n=m.eq(d[i]+1),o=e[i]+j.outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,o),e.push(o),d.push(d[i++]+1),j=n;(f>0&&g+e[i]<0||f<0&&g+e[i]+f<0)&&j.is(m.last())&&(r=Math.max(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[i])/4),-k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[i])),p(l,g+f)},moveEnd:function(a,b,c,f,g,h){var i=d.length,j=p(l),n=i-1,o;if(e[0]+j>0)n=0;else if(!(e[d.length-1]+j<0)){o={pxInMs:b};var s,t,u=i-1,v=k.innerWidth();for(s=0;s<i-1;s++){t=e[s]+m.eq(d[s]).outerWidth()+j;if(t>0&&t>v-(e[s+1]+j)){u=s;break}}if(r)n=u;else{var w=i-1,x=Math.round(l.offset().left);for(s=0;s<i;s++)if(e[s]+x>a.pageX){w=s-1;break}n=u,u===w&&a.timeStamp-f<1e3&&g+h>Math.sqrt(Math.pow(k.height(),2)+Math.pow(v,2))*.05&&(n=Math.max(0,Math.min(i-1,n+c)))}}n=d[n],q.to(n,o)}}}();q.init();if(g){var r=!1;l.bind("webkitTransitionStart",function(){r=!0}),l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){r=!1})}var w=!1,x=!1,y;k.hover(function(){clearTimeout(y),w=!0},function(){w=!1,z()}),n.click(function(){t(n.index(this))}),a(c.prev,e).click(function(){v()}),a(c.next,e).click(function(){u()}),c.mouseTouch&&C(),c.autoplay&&A(),e.data(d,f)},a.fn.touchSlider=function(a){return a=a||{},a.container=this,touchSlider(a),this}})(jQuery);
(function(a,b){window.touchSlider=function(c){function s(a){n.removeClass(c.currentClass).eq(a).addClass(c.currentClass)}function t(a,c){var d=f.current;d!==a&&(a=a!==b?a:d+1,q.to(a,{complete:c}))}function u(a){q.to(f.current+1,{dirX:1,complete:a})}function v(a){q.to(f.current-1,{dirX:-1,complete:a})}function z(){x&&A()}function A(){return x=!0,w||(clearTimeout(y),y=setTimeout(function(){!q.moving&&!w&&u()},c.delay)),c.container}function B(){return clearTimeout(y),x=!1,c.container}function C(){var b=a(document),c,e,f=!1,m,n,o,p,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z=function(a){if(a.which>1)return;f&&b.triggerHandler(j+"."+d),f=!0,e=!1,c=a.timeStamp,s=x=0,m=[0,0,0,c];if(a.originalEvent.touches){b.one(h,A);return}a.preventDefault(),o=p=a.pageX,v=w=a.pageY,u=l[0].offsetLeft,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j+"."+d,C),q.moveStart(a)},A=function(a){if(a.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;o=p=a.pageX=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,v=w=a.pageY=a.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t=y=0,u=(new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(l[0]).webkitTransform)).e,n=[0,0,0,o],b.bind(i,B),b.one(j,C),q.moveStart(a)},B=function(b){var c,d;if(b.originalEvent.touches&&g){if(b.originalEvent.touches.length!==1)return;c=b.pageX=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,d=b.pageY=b.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,t+=Math.abs(c-p),y+=Math.abs(d-w);if(Math.abs(t-y)>50){var f=t;t=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,t-y)),y=Math.min(100,Math.max(0,y-f))}if(c===p)return;e||(t>y?(b.preventDefault(),e=!0):C(b))}else{c=b.pageX,d=b.pageY;if(c===p)return;a.browser.msie&&b.preventDefault()}s+=Math.abs(c-p),x+=Math.abs(d-w),m.shift(),m.push(b.timeStamp),n.shift(),n.push(c),q.move(b,p),p=c,w=d},C=function(a){f=!1;if(!a.originalEvent||a.originalEvent.touches)a.pageX=p,a.pageY=w;b.unbind(i,B);var d=m.length,e=0,g=0;while(--d>0)if(m[d-1]){var h=n[d]-n[d-1];e+=Math.abs(h)/(m[d]-m[d-1]),h!==0&&(g=h>0?-1:1)}e/=m.length,q.moveEnd(a,e,g,c,s,x),r=!1,s+x>4&&k.one("click",function(a){a.preventDefault()})};k.bind(h,z)}c=c||{};var d=c.namespace||"touchslider",e=a(c.container);if(e.length!==1){e.each(function(){touchSlider({container:this})});return}c=a.extend({autoplay:!1,delay:3e3,margin:5,viewport:"."+d+"-viewport",prev:"."+d+"-prev",next:"."+d+"-next",pagination:"."+d+"-nav-item",currentClass:d+"-nav-item-current",duration:350,mouseTouch:!0},c);var f={current:0,step:t,next:u,prev:v,start:A,stop:B},g="ontouchstart"in window&&"WebKitCSSMatrix"in window,h="touchstart",i="touchmove",j="touchend",k=a(c.viewport,e),l=c.scroller?a(c.scroller,e):k.children(),m=l.children(),n=a(c.pagination,e);if(l.css("position")!=="absolute"){var o=k.height();k.css({height:o,position:"relative"}),l.css({position:"absolute",left:0,height:o,width:1e5})}g||(h="mousedown",i="mousemove",j="mouseup"),m.css("position","absolute");var p=g?function(a,c,d){if(c===b)return(new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle(a.jquery?a[0]:a).webkitTransform)).e;a.css({webkitTransitionDuration:d?d+"ms":"0",webkitTransform:function(a){return"translate3d("+(typeof c=="number"?c:c.call(this,a))+"px,0,0)"}})}:function(a,c){if(c===b)return parseInt((a.jquery?a[0]:a).style.left,10);a.css("left",c)};g&&m.css({webkitTransitionProperty:"-webkit-transform",webkitTransitionTimingFunction:"cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1)"}),p(m.not(m[0]),1e4),p(m.eq(0),0);var q=function(){var d=[0],e=[0],h=a.noop;return{moving:!1,init:function(){l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){h()})},to:function(i,j){j=j||{},i>=m.length?i=0:i<0&&(i=m.length-1);var k=c.duration,n=m.eq(i),o=a.inArray(i,d),r=0;l.stop(),q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y);if(o!==-1)r=e[o];else{var t,u=m.index(n);o=b;if(j.dirX===-1)e.unshift(0),d.unshift(u);else if(j.dirX===1)e.push(0),d.push(u);else{for(t=d.length-1;t>=0;t--)if(d[t]<u){e.splice(t+1,0,0),d.splice(t+1,0,u),o=0;break}o===b&&(e.unshift(e),d.unshift(u))}o=a.inArray(u,d);if(o===0)r=e[1]-(n.outerWidth()+c.margin),p(n,r),e[o]=r;else if(o===d.length-1)r=e[o-1]+m.eq(d[o-1]).outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,r),e[o]=r;else{var v=n.outerWidth();n.css("opacity",0),r=e[o+1]-Math.round((v+c.margin)/2),e[o]=r,p(n,r);var w=r,x=d.length;for(t=o-1;t>=0;t--)w-=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=w;var A=r;for(t=o+1;t<x;t++)A+=m.eq(d[t]).outerWidth()+c.margin,e[t]=A;for(t=0;t<x;t++)m.eq(d[t]).animate({left:e[t]},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:function(){n.is(this)&&n.animate({opacity:1},k)}})}}j.pxInMs&&(k=Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(Math.abs(p(l))/j.pxInMs),100),k)),h=function(){p(m.not(n),-1e4),d=[m.index(n)],e=[r],j.complete&&j.complete(),q.moving=!1,z()},g?p(l,-r,k):l.animate({left:-r},{duration:k,queue:!1,complete:h}),f.current=i,s(i)},stop:function(){g?p(l,p(l)):l.stop()},moveStart:function(a){q.moving=!0,clearTimeout(y),l.stop(),q.startPageX=a.pageX;var b=p(l),c;q.leftCount=b,d[0]===0?e[0]+b>0&&(q.leftCount=b+(e[0]+b)*3):d[d.length-1]===m.length-1&&(c=e[d.length-1]+b,c<0&&(q.leftCount=b+c*3))},move:function(a,b){var f=a.pageX-b,g=p(l),h=m.eq(d[0]),i=d.length-1,j=m.eq(d[i]),n,o,r;q.leftCount+=f;if(f>0)while(d[0]!==0&&g+e[0]+f>c.margin)n=m.eq(d[0]-1),o=e[0]-n.outerWidth()-c.margin,p(n,o),e.unshift(o),d.unshift(d[0]-1),i++,h=n;(f>0&&g+e[0]+f>0||f<0&&g+e[0]>0)&&d[0]===0&&(r=Math.min(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[0])/4),k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[0]));if(f<0)while(!j.is(m.last())&&g+e[i]+f+j.outerWidth()+c.margin<k.innerWidth())n=m.eq(d[i]+1),o=e[i]+j.outerWidth()+c.margin,p(n,o),e.push(o),d.push(d[i++]+1),j=n;(f>0&&g+e[i]<0||f<0&&g+e[i]+f<0)&&j.is(m.last())&&(r=Math.max(Math.round((q.leftCount+e[i])/4),-k.innerWidth()/2),f=r-(g+e[i])),p(l,g+f)},moveEnd:function(a,b,c,f,g,h){var i=d.length,j=p(l),n=i-1,o;if(e[0]+j>0)n=0;else if(!(e[d.length-1]+j<0)){o={pxInMs:b};var s,t,u=i-1,v=k.innerWidth();for(s=0;s<i-1;s++){t=e[s]+m.eq(d[s]).outerWidth()+j;if(t>0&&t>v-(e[s+1]+j)){u=s;break}}if(r)n=u;else{var w=i-1,x=Math.round(l.offset().left);for(s=0;s<i;s++)if(e[s]+x>a.pageX){w=s-1;break}n=u,u===w&&a.timeStamp-f<1e3&&g+h>Math.sqrt(Math.pow(k.height(),2)+Math.pow(v,2))*.05&&(n=Math.max(0,Math.min(i-1,n+c)))}}n=d[n],q.to(n,o)}}}();q.init();if(g){var r=!1;l.bind("webkitTransitionStart",function(){r=!0}),l.bind("webkitTransitionEnd",function(){r=!1})}var w=!1,x=!1,y;k.hover(function(){clearTimeout(y),w=!0},function(){w=!1,z()}),n.click(function(){t(n.index(this))}),a(c.prev,e).click(function(){v()}),a(c.next,e).click(function(){u()}),c.mouseTouch&&C(),c.autoplay&&A(),e.data(d,f)},a.fn.touchSlider=function(a){return a=a||{},a.container=this,touchSlider(a),this}})(jQuery);
```

```css
.touchslider{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);}


.touchslider-viewport{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
overflow: hidden;
}

.touchslider-viewport-div{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}

.touchslider-item{
width:100%;
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}

.touchslider-viewport-div-image{
width: -webkit-calc(100vw - 25px);
width:    -moz-calc(100vw - 25px);
width:         calc(100vw - 25px);
height: -webkit-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:    -moz-calc(50vw - 25px);
height:         calc(50vw - 25px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="touchslider hideslide">


<div class="touchslider-viewport">


<div class="touchslider-viewport-div">
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/20b-woodlawn.php"><img src="slider/20b-woodlawn.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image"  /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/73-macpherson.php"><img src="slider/73-macpherson.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><a href="listings/232-lonsmount.php"><img src="slider/232-lonsmount.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></a></div>
    <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="slider/sign.jpg" class="round touchslider-viewport-div-image" /></div>



</div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(".touchslider").touchSlider({container: this,
duration: 800, // the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
delay: 5000, // initial auto-scrolling delay for each loop 
margin: 3, // borders size. The margin is set in pixels.
mouseTouch: true,
namespace: "touchslider",
next: ".touchslider-next", // jQuery object for the elements to which a "scroll forwards" action should be bound.
pagination: ".touchslider-nav-item",
currentClass: "touchslider-nav-item-current", // class name for current     pagination item.
prev: ".touchslider-prev", // jQuery object for the elements to which a     "scroll backwards" action should be bound.
autoplay: true, // Activate auto-scrolling, choose either "true" or "false"
viewport: ".touchslider-viewport"});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for some reason the slider is no longer even working. I am getting this error: 

"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: I also had this error when I copied your code. You forgot to include jQuery in it, I added it to my snippet. Be sure to add it in your local code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. I don't understand what you mean, could you explain? The slider is unfortunately not working at all anymore. Do you mean this code? __ <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> __ I had this code before: __<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" async="async"></script>

Comment: I don't understand where it's not working. As you can see in my above minimal snippet everything works just fine. Could you please provide non-working JSFriddle?

Comment: I had moved around the jQuery on the page, I just referenced an older backup file I had and restored the original jQuery. The slider is now working again. ------ I tried your solution and it didn't work. The non-mobile version of the CSS file already included the overflow:hidden element. Any more thoughts? You can now view the page again if you would like to see the working slider.

Comment: Well, if slider works then I don't understand what is an issue here. You say my snippet doesn't work, yet it works right here, on SO. I don't understand what is the problem now.

Comment: I broke the slider and it wasn't working at all. It is now working again, but I am still having the same original problem. I think you are correct that it has something to do with the touchslider-item class in the css, because when I inspect the div it seems to extend beyond the edge of the page. I'm just not sure what I need to change in the css. I thought 100% would fit the divs container, but for some reason it seems to be much much larger.

Comment: If you can't [provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with precise description of what needs to be done, then I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Banman. It's a pleasure to help you. I have reviewed your code and the problem you mention is due to the fact that you used specific values. For example I found this line:

```
<div style="text-align:center;height:5px;/* width: 1000px; */position: relative;">
        <span class="touchslider-prev" style="cursor:pointer; z-index: 40;"><span class="prevbutton"></span></span>
        <span class="touchslider-next" style="cursor:pointer; z-index: 40;"><span class="nextbutton"></span></span>
    </div>
```

I recommend that you change the **width: 1000px** for another unit of measure such as **width: 100vw** or **width: 100%**

It has several elements with the same structure:

**width: 1000px**

this causes the overflow of your website. I changed this into three elements of your site and solve the problem.Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joel. The specific values you are talking about are only for the positions of the navigation buttons for the slider. Do these affect the functionality of the slider itself? You can also click+drag the slider to move browse the images.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. If you want to get a responsive design you should not use absolute values ​​like this. I found in your code some **img** with  **width: 1000px**

Comment: Hmmmm, I removed the navigation buttons from the page and it didn't change anything. I double checked my code, and used the inspector to check for 1000px values and couldn't find any. Is there anything you can think of that is causing the problem?